# Error while buying test ether from https://faucet.metamask.io/ - Mastering Ethereum

Tags: metamask, ropsten, mastering-ethereum

I am using Ethereum wallet MetaMask chrome extension and I am connected to Ropsten test network. I am following the instructions from the book Mastering Ethereum: Building Smart Contracts and DApps book by Andreas Antonopoulos and Gavin Wood.

When requesting 1 ether from faucet I get the following error:

```
{"error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"message\":\"Internal error\",\"code\":-32603}}'"}
```

The wallet seems to have plenty of ether available so I'm not sure what the exact issue is. Can someone please provide guidance? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm still having the same issue even with the https://faucet.ropsten.be/.
Is this not working in 2020?

Answer (score 7):

Don't make it so hard for you. Just use a working faucet. None of us can fix a problem with the faucet you mentioned.

**Here is a working Ropsten Testnet Faucet:**

https://faucet.ropsten.be/

Comment: Nah, it doesn't work.

Comment: for some reason, my address is always in its blacklist. It's really annoying

Comment: any solution? same problem

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is give it a few minutes.

I was having trouble with both [Metamask's Faucet](https://faucet.metamask.io/) and [Ropsten.be](https://faucet.ropsten.be/), then started looking at how to mine it myself and found this article [reddit article](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/pg36y9/cant_get_test_ether_form_faucet_metamask/). While installing [Go Ethereum](https://geth.ethereum.org/), the transaction had been made to my account.