# Why am I getting "Too Many Requests" / "[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC" error from faucet.metamask.io

Tags: ether, testnets, ropsten, faucets

I am simply trying to get some test ether on Ropsten network from https://faucet.metamask.io/ and I keep getting this error. Any suggestion:

```
Error: 500 {"error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"message\":\"Too Many Requests\",\"data\":{\"originalError\":{}},\"stack\":\"Error: Too Many Requests\\n at eval (/www/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:52:23)\\n at Request.eval [as _callback] (/www/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:54:11)\\n at Request.self.callback (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)\\n at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)\\n at Request.eval (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:1155:10)\\n at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)\\n at IncomingMessage.eval (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:1077:12)\\n at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)\\n at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)\\n at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)\"}}'"}
```

Here's the inner message from the above reformatted for readability:

```json
{
    "value":{
        "code": -32603,
        "message": "Too Many Requests",
        "data": {"originalError":{}},
        "stack": "Error: Too Many Requests
 at eval (/www/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:52:23)
 at Request.eval [as _callback] (/www/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:54:11)
 at Request.self.callback (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
 at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
 at Request.eval (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:1155:10)
 at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
 at IncomingMessage.eval (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:1077:12)
 at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
 at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
 at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar question though with a slightly different error: [Error while buying test ether from https://faucet.metamask.io/ - Mastering Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77845/error-while-buying-test-ether-from-https-faucet-metamask-io-mastering-ether)

Answer (score 1):

This faucet isnt working for like 2 years.Try to find a different faucet or i could send you if you need

Comment: do oyu have some information on how to mine test ether

Comment: nah idk how to do it.But its possible ig. You could try this for example https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-mine-ropsten-testnet-ether-keir-finlow-bates